# how to access the node red static directory

Tags: ubuntu, node-red

on Ubuntu would you know where the node red `static` directory would be located?

There's a [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_PNhLYj8INs) video where I can append CSV files and serve them through the node red static directory and retrieve the CSV data through the browser but I am having a difficult time trying to find where the `static` directory exists.

I can access the node red `settings.js` no problem here

`ben@ben-HP-ProBook-6550b:~/.node-red$`

When I can nano `settings.js` I did uncomment out:

`httpStatic: '/home/nol/node-red-static/'`

[image]

But the only thing that exists in /home is:

```
ben@ben-HP-ProBook-6550b:/home$ ls
ben
```

No `nol` directory, any ideas to try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/home/nol/node-red-static` setting is only intended to be an example path. You need to provide the full path to whatever directory you want to use for your static files.